# kendo-ui grid filter icon not displaying

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

Filter icon not displaying in the tab. But when I try to click in the last filter options displayed.
How to show filter icon and what code I need to write..

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        dataBound: function(){
            updateGridForStage(stage)
            riskGridTitle()
        },
        height: 'auto',
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: Object,
        pageable: false,
        columns: [
            { field: "subject", title: "Subject", width: "40%" },
            { field: "status", title: "Status", width: "30%" },
            { field: "risk", title: "Score", width: "10%" },
            { field: "owner", title: "Owner", width: "25%" },
            { field: "days_open", title: "Days Open", width: "15%" },
            { field: "next_review", title: "Next Review Date", width: "25%" },
            { command}]
});
```

"I need to display icon near status"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do just `true` instead of `object`

```
filterable: true
```